# Passing Axios data to pdfmake [Vuejs3 and Laravel 9]

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, pdfmake

I'm studying passing Axios data to pdfmake.

Basic CRUD and PDF generate are working good.
but I can't pass single Axios record and add to pdf code.

I copy show.vue and changed as pdf.vue.
so I can successfully get specific record data.

Could you teach me what is causing please?

companiesIndex.vue

```
// When user click this link PDF will generate.
<router-link :to="{ name: 'companies.est', params: { id: item.id } }" class="">
PDF
</router-link>
```

> index.js

```
import CompaniesEst from '@/components/companies/CompaniesEst.vue'
 {
        path: '/companies/:id/est',
        name: 'companies.est',
        component: CompaniesEst,
        props: true
    },
```

PDF generate vue file
companiesEst.vue

```
<template>
    I'm not sure about this line.
    I would like to When User click comapniesIndex instantly go companies.est and generate PDF

            
    <button @click="exportPdf">Gen PDF</button> 
</template>

<script setup>
import useCompanies from "@/composables/companies";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

import * as pdfFonts from  'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs

const { errors, company, getCompany, updateCompany } = useCompanies()
const props = defineProps({
    id: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    }
})

onMounted(getCompany(props.id))

const saveCompany = async () => {
    await updateCompany(props.id)
}

 
 
// PDF generate section 
pdfMake.fonts = {
  Ipaex: {
      normal: 'ipaexg.ttf',
      bold:   'ipaexm.ttf'
    }
}
const defaultStyle = "Ipaex"

function exportPdf() {
  const name = company.name 
    let document = {    
    content: [
    { 
          columns: [
          
           {
            text: name ,
           
          },
          ]
          ],
          
      defaultStyle: {
            font:defaultStyle
        }
    }   
    pdfMake.createPdf(document).download('estimate.pdf');
}
```